# Understanding repeated covariance types in SPSS?

Tags: mixed-model, spss, repeated-measures, references, covariance

I am working in SPSS on a repeated measures linear mixed model and I am having a really hard time wrapping my head around how to select a "repeated covariance type". The options are:

- Ante-Dependence:First Order
- AR1
- AR1 Heterogenous
- ARMA
- Compound Symmetry
- Compound Symmetry: Correlation Metric
- Compound Symmetry: Heterogenous
- Diagonal
- Factor Analytic: First Order
- Factor Analytic: First Order, Heterogeneous
- Huynh-Feldt
- Scaled Identity
- Toeplitz
- Toeplitz: Heterogenous
- Unstructured
- Unstructured:Correlations

For my study, I am looking at bird calls and how they change under certain manipulated conditions.

1. Can anyone recommend any resources that clearly explain the different covariance types? I am struggling to understand their differences and in what instances you should use each. I've looked at the SPSS manual and that hasn't been helpful.
2. With so many options it seems there might be more than one "right answer" - how do you determine which one to use then? Obviously once I have better resources I will be able to eliminate some options and narrow it down, but what parameter should I be looking at to assess if I have selected the right covariance type or not? Is there a test I can do along with the LMM that will give me a value related to the covariance that I can look at to evaluate its appropriateness?

Comment: Be aware that this question is awfully broad, & may be closed as too broad. If so, you may prefer to ask a series of more focused questions. You may also want to read through our [materials](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/asking) on asking questions on CV.

Comment: Ok thank you for the feedback - I am editing it to be more specific!

Comment: You note that you have "come on here for help... before", but I notice that your account is unregistered & is not associated with any other question. Please register your account & merge whatever [accounts](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/account) you have.

Comment: I dont understand, I always use the same email address?

Comment: Either way, my previous question I was helped with on here does not really have anything to do with what I am asking now (it was about dealing with repeated measures and unbalanced data)... But as far as my question now, do you have any way in which you can help me?

Comment: Someone may be able to help you, also this Q may end up being closed as too broad, IDK. Re your account, if you go to your [userpage](http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/49393/jazz), you will see that the other Q's are not listed. Please register your account.

Comment: Im just a masters student with an advisor thats trying to retire and a crappy stats department - so, I dont have any support (which is how I got in to this complicated mess of a project to begin with). I am just trying my hardest to teach myself the material and to make sure I am doing a good job. I dont know how else to narrow my question down other than what I already did. Im just looking for some help or guidance, but if that's not possible then by all means close the question down. I will keep trying my best at figuring this out. Thanks though.

Comment: Your question has been up for 2 hours. It may take a while. You are welcome to come here for help w/ your questions. I sympathize w/ your situation, just please register your account.